# What is the cleanest way to set up a remote control of my desktop from my laptop?

Tags: networking, remote-access, remote-desktop

So, to use some simulation tools and the raw power of the fully armed and operational battlestation that is my Windows 7 desktop, from my Windows 10 laptop, I was hoping to finally try my hand at setting up some sort of remote control between the two.

Particularly, I want to

1. Be able to control my desktop from my laptop (duh)
2. To be able to start the remote control software remotely, meaning all that will need to be done is fire up and log in on the desktop, then the laptop can handle the rest.
3. To be able to do this over the internet, not over a LAN connection.
4. To be able to do all of the above, at a reasonable speed, without too noticeable a latency, for my own sanity when typing code over this connection.

So, have any of you done something like this before?  I'm sure there's someone out there whose dabbled with this before.

Optional, edited out requirements to replace, or accompany #2 if possible:

2a.  Be able to put my desktop in standby mode for a few days (for power concerns) over this remote connection, then wake it back up using the remote connection over the laptop
2b.  Be able to log into the password protected admin account on the desktop over this remote connection, after waking from safe mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By setting up a DDNS, port forwarding, and enabling wake on LAN, TeamViewer can provide all of the functionality I needed, even waking it from standbyover the internet.

Answer (score 1):

You could try TeamViewer, I don't think that you can do #2 and #3 tho.
But you can also control it with your smartphone.
Actually I don't think you can do #2 and #3 with any remote control software, that needs a physical switch.

Comment: I've seen something called "Wake over LAN", allowing outside connections to take a computer off of standby mode, so I know something like it is possible, however it may only be so over a LAN connection, therefore making the bottleneck #4 instead

Comment: I don't think you can do that outside of a LAN connection. Security issues.

Comment: Hmm, alright, I'll revise my question to the absolute minimum requirements, meaning someone will have to turn on and log into my computer for me when I need to do work...

Comment: However, I do want to add that I don't want to use TeamViewer unless as a last resort.  I've used it before and find its service good, but at the same time I feel like it isn't meant for this kind of project...